# XCTest: [UIApplication sharedApplication] is returning nil

Tags: objective-c, swift, xctest, uiapplication

I have written a framework with all the utility(Common) functions in Objective-C. Since it is a framework, it does not have an App delegate file.

I have created an UIApplication class and have few utility methods in it.

```
@interface TestApplication : UIApplication
{
- (void)initialLockSetUp;
// more...
}
```

Now from my unit tests file, how can I test this "initialLockSetUp" method?
When I call `(TestApplication*)[UIApplication sharedApplication]`, it is returning nil.

Comment: Have you tried changing the testing target?

Comment: Why would you need a subclass of `UIApplication`?

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you need a `UIApplication` instance for your tests, the test host for your test target should be an application.  You can then link your framework to that test target.  Now `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` will return a valid `UIApplication` instance.  The OS creates this instance when the app launches, so you won't be able to subclass it.

Here's a screenshot of the project settings:

[image]